# Tanto X como Y - ¿importa el orden?

Tags: traducción, sintaxis, orden-de-palabras

Estoy traduciendo una frase de inglés:

> Instructions are available in both English and Spanish.

La estructura que me parece más natural para este uso de *both* es *tanto ... como ...*:

> Las instrucciones están disponibles tanto en inglés como en castellano.

¿Tengo razón en creer que así lleva cierta connotación de "Claro que están en castellano, pero la versión inglesa es un plus"? O sea, ¿cambia el significado si pongo así?

> Las instrucciones están disponibles tanto en castellano como en inglés.

Prefiero poner el castellano primero en la traducción castellana porque es lo que más interesa a los hispanohablantes, pero no quiero dar la impresión de que es una opción inferior.

Comment: I'm not sure that *tanto...como...* is the best translation here (but I'll let a native speaker confirm or deny my suspicion).  I would have said simply *Las instrucciones están disponibles en inglés y español.* Or if the word **both** was important for some reason (it's really filler even in English) *...en los dos inglés y español.*

Comment: @Flimzy the English form "both... and..." is usually translated as "tanto... como...". I think it's the best translation in this case. Your translation is also OK but "tanto... como" emphasizes more as "both" does. "en los dos inglés y español" doesn't sound as natural as "tanto... como"

Comment: @Javi: Thanks for the clarification.  *tanto...como...* has other possible meanings/translations too, no?

Comment: @Peter Taylor Order (when meaning word order) is a masculine word so the tile should be "¿importa el orden?"

Comment: Actually I see *tanto...como...* more like this: *as much/(adjective/adverb here) as*... But I see the "both" translation works too...

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, for example in a sentence like "Ana tiene tanto dinero como Pedro" it would be "Ana has as much money as Pedro" so it could be "as much/many... as..." in comparisons.

Comment: @Javi: That's the *tanto..como..* form I'm familiar with... glad I learned something new today :)

Comment: Gracias, @Javi. Es uno de mis errores particulares que necesito erradicar.

Comment: @Peter Taylor don't worry "orden" is a difficult word because it can be masculine (e.g. when meaning "sequence", "harmony") and femenine (when meaning "a command", "an institution")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that they have the same meaning, the order in this case doesn't affect it because you're equalling both terms.

Maybe if you were comparing people and you were one of them, "yourself" should be used in the last place because there's a proverb which says:

> El burro delante para que no se espante

which means that it's impolite to name in enumerations the others before yourself like:

> En la casa estábamos yo, Pedro y María. [not an error but impolite]
>
> En la casa estábamos Pedro, María y yo. [polite]

This is not exactly an enumeration but probably it could also applied to "tanto .. como" so you should use:

> tanto ella como yo

but it would be the same as saying "tanto yo como ella"

Comment: sería interesante saber que dice la RAE al respecto. Yo hice una pregunta al respecto bajo el contexto inglés en _English Language and Usage_: [Is naming the first person last proper grammar or just proper manners?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/is-naming-the-first-person-last-proper-grammar-or-just-proper-manners)